# What does the expression "then on" mean in this case?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, lyrics, poetry

> She says that she knows that moments are rare
>   I suppose that it's true
>   Then on she goes to say I don't care and she knows that I do

"Then on" means that she said he doesn't care immediately after she saying that she knows that moments are rare? Or we cant't define when she said that he doesn't care?

Comment: It's not 'then on' but rather **on she goes** which is reordered to preserve the rhyme (this seems like a part of a poem; providing context would help). So it is: she **[goes on](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/go-on?q=go+on)** which can have several meanings; since it says that she said one thing and then went on we can safely assume that she said the other part right after the first one.

Comment: Thank you Lucky, this is really a interesting way of constructing the sentence. 
So, could I rewrite this sentence this way?
"Then she goes on and say that I don't care."

Comment: Not really, has to be 'on to' - after one thing, then on to the next thing. 'with' is possible in my example but not yours. 'and' sounds awkward in both cases.

Comment: @Tetsujin I interpreted *to* as an infinitive marker here - I wouldn't say "she goes on to" "say", but "she goes on" "to say" @ Apprentice "and" does sound a bit strange (or at least less elegant), but if you used it it would have to be: "she goes on and say**s**" because when you take out "to" present simple, and not bare infinitive fits here. Of course, the poem wouldn't rhyme there any more.

Answer (score 0):

"On __ goes" is an archaic phrase that means "__ goes on." The blank can be any personal pronoun such as:

- "On she goes."
- "On he goes."
- "On it goes."
- "On I go."
- "On they go."

In modern usage, this conveys a specific tone of being old-fashioned or poetic. It also has an idiomatic meaning to mean roughly "someone who is talking too much and the listener is bored or frustrated with the conversation."

In this example, the sentence should be parsed as *then + on she goes* (as a phrase). It uses *then* as a transition and time indicator to show that the next part comes after the sentence before. As commentors pointed out, this writing may have used this phrase to maintain a poem's meter and rhyme scheme. Alternatively, they may be using it in the idiomatic way to show that the narrator is frustrated at the fact that "she" is continuing to talk in this moment.

### Other Examples

Here are some other examples of the phrase "on __ goes":

*In [Viking Women: Life and Lore (2023)](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Viking_Women/E9WTEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22on%20she%20goes%22&pg=PT138&printsec=frontcover), the author describes a character running even though she is very tired as*

> **On she goes**, each step heavier than the last.

This is an example of an author using this phrasing to invoke a historic and poetic feeling.

*In [The Advisor (1853)](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Adviser/-f8EAAAAQAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22on+she+goes%22&pg=PA271&printsec=frontcover), the author describes a ship making a long and fast voyage with*

> **On she goes**, and on, and on. [...] She will be spoken of as having made the best and speediest passage on record -- **on she goes**.

In a mid-1900s book, this phrase is used to both start and end the sentence to show a particularly poetic and romantic feeling to the ship's journey. Note that this is using the pronoun "she" to refer to the ship as was the style at the time.

*In the [transcript of a US House of Representatives hearing from 1947](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Hearings_Before_and_Special_Reports_Made/XRiKaJOMR4oC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22on+it+goes%22&pg=PA505&printsec=frontcover), the speaker describes being transferred many times between assignments.*

> In the Navy, for instance, my situation was, I started my flying in fighter squadrons. Then I was put in flying patrol squadrons, and then I was shifted back to fighter squadrons, and so **on it goes**.

In this case, the speaker (who is a soldier called before the US House), is likely using this phrase to indicate both formality and tiredness with the events he is describing. In English, using less common word order can be seen as fancy or formal.

Comment: "On X goes" isn't archaic. It's still used, albeit sometimes in a playful or jocular way.

Comment: @StuartF That's interesting! I'm curious where you live and what types of social circles you mostly spend time in? I'm in the northeast US, and although I definitely do hear this sometimes, it's nearly always in a context where the speaker is trying to create an old-timey feeling or an air of formality. Notably, when I did a Google Books search for several different types of the pattern, the first page was almost exclusively books from the 1850s - early 1900s, aside from the Viking Women book which is historical in nature.